# save multiple histograms in folder from a python code

Tags: python, numpy

I have a loop to generate millions of histograms in python and i need to store them all in one folder in my laptop is there a way to save them all without the need of pressing save button each time a histogram generated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `matplotlib`, then what you are looking for is `plt.savefig()`. The documentation is here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Some random data:
x = np.random.rand(100)

fig = plt.figure(1)         # create a figure instance
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   # and axes
ax.hist(x)                  # plot the histogram

# plt.show()                # this would show the plot, but you can leave it out 

# Save the figure to the current path
fig.savefig('test_image.png')
```